# Having an if statement place an 'x' in cell on rows that met the conditions?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So below I have a script which runs in google sheets that sends out an email if my budget has reached 99% of its spend.

What I would like to add is that it places an x in column 18 once it sends out an email. This way I can have it run daily but only send out the email one time.

So monthMetaEmailed is the value of column 18. If monthMetaEmailed is blank it sends out the email, if monthMetaEmailed has an x in the cell it would not.

Here is the script as it stands now,

```
function CheckMeta() {
  // Fetch the rows from PM Master Sheet
  var startRow = 5;
  var numRows = 150;
  var startColumn = 17;
  var numColumns = 1;   
  var i = 150
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sept '20").getRange(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns);
  var monthMeta = sheet.getValues();
  var sheetNames = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sept '20").getRange(startRow, 6, numRows, numColumns);
  var monthMetaNames = sheetNames.getValues();
  var sheetBudget = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sept '20").getRange(startRow, 16, numRows, numColumns);
  var monthMetaBudget = sheetBudget.getValues();
  var sheetSpent = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sept '20").getRange(startRow, 49, numRows, numColumns);
  var monthMetaSpent = sheetSpent.getValues();
  var sheetEmailed = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sept '20").getRange(startRow, 18, numRows, numColumns);
  var monthMetaEmailed = sheetSpent.getValues();
  
  // Check meta pacing
  for (let i = 0; i < monthMeta.length; i++)
  for (let n = i; n < monthMetaNames.length; n++)
  for (let x = i; x < monthMetaBudget.length; x++)
  for (let y = i; y < monthMetaSpent.length; y++)
  for (let v = i; v < monthMetaEmailed.length; v++)
  {
    if ((monthMeta[i] >= .99) && (monthMetaEmailed[v] == '') && (i===n) && (i===x) && (i===y))  {
      
    
 
    // Fetch the email address
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email").getRange("B2");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
  
    // Send Alert Email.
    var message = 'Meta for ' + monthMetaNames[n] + ' is currently pacing at ' + monthMeta[i] + ' it has currently spent ' + monthMetaSpent[y] + ' out of ' + monthMetaBudget[x]; 
    var subject = monthMetaNames[n] + ' Meta Budget Depleted';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
 
      
     
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Well its the first time I have ever even tried doing anything with code so that is probably a given. Still, it does work.

Comment: How does it work? I see 2d arrays in your code and you are accessing using one index only. For example, `monthMeta` is a 2D array. What is the value of `monthMeta[i]` ?

Comment: Nevertheless, I think you are looking for something like: `sheet.getRange(i+startRow,18).setValue('x')` . Can you try this out anywhere inside the if statement? Please let me know if it worked.

Comment: tbh I'm not sure why it works but prior to trying to add the sections for MonthMetaEmailed it did correctly email me any rows that hit the >=.99 with the matching name/spend/budget of those rows. Ended up going with what the other commenter wrote because obviously it was better than mine but thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be cleaned up by putting things that you reuse inside of a variable. Lets clean things up a bit first.

```
 function CheckMeta() {
  // Fetch the rows from PM Master Sheet
  var startRow = 5;
  var numRows = 150;
  var startColumn = 17;
  var numColumns = 1;   
  var i = 150
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sept '20")

  var sheet = spreadsheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns);
  var monthMeta = sheet.getValues();
  var sheetNames = spreadsheet.getRange(startRow, 6, numRows, numColumns);
  var monthMetaNames = sheetNames.getValues();
  var sheetBudget = spreadsheet.getRange(startRow, 16, numRows, numColumns);
  var monthMetaBudget = sheetBudget.getValues();
  var sheetSpent = spreadsheet.getRange(startRow, 49, numRows, numColumns);
  var monthMetaSpent = sheetSpent.getValues();
  var sheetEmailed = spreadsheet.getRange(startRow, 18, numRows, numColumns);
  var monthMetaEmailed = sheetSpent.getValues();
```

Now, since the lines arent so long, lets get rid of vairables you only use once

```
   function CheckMeta() {
  // Fetch the rows from PM Master Sheet
  var startRow = 5;
  var numRows = 150;
  var startColumn = 17;
  var numColumns = 1;   
  var i = 150
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sept '20")

  var monthMeta = spreadsheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns).getValues();
  var monthMetaNames = spreadsheet.getRange(startRow, 6, numRows, numColumns).getValues();
  var monthMetaBudget = spreadsheet.getRange(startRow, 16, numRows, numColumns).getValues();
  var monthMetaSpent = spreadsheet.getRange(startRow, 49, numRows, numColumns).getValues();
  var monthMetaEmailed = spreadsheet.getRange(startRow, 18, numRows, numColumns).getValues();
```

OK, now its easier to read, lets get to your issue.
I cant work out what this does without your data, so I'm going to assume it works

```
  for (let i = 0; i < monthMeta.length; i++)
  for (let n = i; n < monthMetaNames.length; n++)
  for (let x = i; x < monthMetaBudget.length; x++)
  for (let y = i; y < monthMetaSpent.length; y++)
  for (let v = i; v < monthMetaEmailed.length; v++)
  {
    if ((monthMeta[i] >= .99) && (monthMetaEmailed[v] == '') && (i===n) && (i===x) && (i===y))  {
```

monthMetaEmailed is already check for text, so we just need to put an 'x' when we send an email. Do it here:

```
// Send Alert Email.
var message = 'Meta for ' + monthMetaNames[n] + ' is currently pacing at ' + monthMeta[i] + ' it has currently spent ' + monthMetaSpent[y] + ' out of ' + monthMetaBudget[x]; 
var subject = monthMetaNames[n] + ' Meta Budget Depleted';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
spreadsheet.getRange(v, 18).setValue('x')
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `getValues()` multiple times when you could get the entire range & values once. Because of this, and without seeing your data, it's quite challenging to understand what's going on.

This response doesn't attempt to fix your exact scenario, but instead assumes an example inspired by your question and shows you a different approach to your problem. Please go through it and see how calling `getValues()` once also allows me to have only one loop. This makes the code much easier to understand.

Here is the data I'm using for the example.
[image]

```
function CheckMeta() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // Fetch the email address
  var emailRange = ss.getSheetByName("Email").getRange("B2");
  var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
  
  // Define your column indexes.
  // Ranges start at 1, but the first element in an array begins at 0.
  var monthCol = 1;
  var budgetCol = 2;
  var spentCol = 3;
  var paceCol = 4;
  var emailedCol = 5;
  
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sept '20");
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
  var table = dataRange.getValues();
  
  for (var rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < table.length; rowIndex++) {
    var row = table[rowIndex];
    var month = row[monthCol-1]; // Offsetting by 1 because it's an array
    var budget = row[budgetCol-1];
    var spent = row[spentCol-1];
    var pace = row[paceCol-1];
    var emailed = row[emailedCol-1];
    if (pace >= .99 && emailed == "") {
      sendBudgetAlert(emailAddress, month, pace, spent, budget);
      sheet.getRange(rowIndex+1, emailedCol).setValue("x");
    }
  }
  
  function sendBudgetAlert(emailAddress, month, pace, spent, budget) {
    var message = 'Meta for ' + month + ' is currently pacing at ' + pace + ' it has currently spent ' + spent + ' out of ' + budget; 
    var subject = month + ' Meta Budget Depleted';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do and worked great once I updated for my own columns. Thanks! Didn't realize I could break out columns into different variables like that which is why I thought I had to get the values of each one independently.